# How to Create Image Fingerprint using Opencv?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, fingerprint, feature-extraction

I have a project about image similarity. I've tried Opencv feature [detector-discrioptor-matcher] methods. The combination is that ORB-ORB-BruteForce is best. But, want to create a fingerprint using this methods and save on DB.

How to create a fingerprint for image similarity search?

Thanks.

Comment: you can try a bag of words approach.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision

Comment: apart from opencv, looking at [phash](http://www.phash.org/) might be another idea